# MongoDB NodeJS driver disconnects unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Trying to create a "register user" page. And will store the data in Mongodb cloud.

I took part of the connection example from the docs. But when inserting a document it errors out without much information.

This is the basic example:

```
import express from "express";
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";// for hashing pwd
import dotenv from "dotenv";// imports .env as object

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

const uri = process.env.MONGOURI
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

async function run() {
  try {
    
    // Connect to MongoDB
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db('chatApp');
    const users = database.collection('users');

    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true})); //Parse URL-encoded bodies

    app.post("/register", async(req,res) => {

      const { username, password } = req.body

      // create hash and then..
      const newUser = await users.insertOne({_id:username, password: hash}); //ERRORS!
      console.log(newUser)
      res.send("done")

    });

} finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}

run().catch(console.dir);

app.listen(3000, ()=>console.log("listening on 3000"))
```

Getting this error:

> MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation
> at getTopology (/home/p/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:282:11)
> ...

> at Collection.insertOne (/home/p/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:149:57)

Why is it disconnecting?

Comment: I tested your code. It ran successfully. ```console.log()```  this parameters: ```process.env.MONGOURI``` ```database``` ```users```

Comment: I found that the problem was the MongoClient should be created inside the async run, I believe it makes sense but can not yet explain it. @AliShefaee

Comment: sorry i meant the client as in `client.connect()` inside the app.post!

Answer (score 0):

When it runs the **run()** async it:

1. Connects to DB
2. Listens to post requests
3. Closes the connection

If I add a console.log in the finally block, this is what I get:

```
listening on 3000
connected
closing...
```

So that is the problem.

If you are not doing a one time transaction like an api but serving constantly content, you dont close the connection..:

```
async function run() {

    // Connect to MongoDB
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db('chatApp');
    const users = database.collection('users');

    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true})); //Parse URL-encoded bodies

    app.post("/register", async(req,res) => {

      const { username, password } = req.body

      // create hash and then..
      const newUser = await users.insertOne({_id:username, password: hash}); //ERRORS!
      console.log(newUser)
      res.send("done")

    });
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```